# Normalization of a projective curve over a field doesn't add new constant functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $k$ is a field (not necessarily algebraically closed, no characteristic assumptions) and $X\to\operatorname{Spec} k$ is a curve over $k$ (a projective integral separated scheme over $k$ of dimension one). Let $\nu:\widetilde{X}\to X$ denote the normalization. Is it true that $\mathcal{O}_X(X)\cong \mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}(\widetilde{X})$?

### My efforts:

I'm proceeding under the hope this is true, but I haven't gotten very far.

I already know that the global sections of any proper integral scheme over $k$ is a finite extension of $k$, so the goal is to explain why normalization doesn't add anything here. So restrict to an affine open $\operatorname{Spec} A\subset X$ with normalization $\operatorname{Spec} A'\subset \widetilde{X}$ - because restriction maps are injective in integral schemes, this exhibits the global sections of $X$ and $\widetilde{X}$ as subrings of $A$ and $A'$ respectively, each integral over the respective copy of $k$. Let $a,b$ be two elements of $A$ with $a/b$ integral over $\mathcal{O}_X(X)\subset A$. Clearly I need to argue that $a,b\in \mathcal{O}_X(X)$, but I don't see how to do this.

Alternatively, since normalization is birational, it must be an isomorphism on a dense open set. So if the constant functions can be detected from a dense open subset, then we'd be in business. But I'm worried about having some constant function defined on a dense open subset which doesn't extend (I know this seems silly, but I can't explain my way out of this). I guess that maybe we would want to say that the constant functions are the maximal subfield of the coordinate algebra of an affine open, but I don't know how to prove that or if it's correct. Or the constants are the maximal subfield contained in every residue field, but how do I know that this is birational? I suspect it isn't - take something like $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$ with just one real point.

### Motivation:

I'm working on Hartshorne chapter 2 exercise 6.9a. The goal is to show that in the above situation, there's an exact sequence $$0\to \bigoplus \widetilde{\mathcal{O}_P}^\times/\mathcal{O}_P^\times \to \operatorname{Pic} X\to \operatorname{Pic} \widetilde{X}\to 0.$$
Via the hint, I can show that there's an exact sequence $$0\to \bigoplus \widetilde{\mathcal{O}_P}^\times/\mathcal{O}_P^\times \to \operatorname{CaDiv} X \to \operatorname{CaDiv} \widetilde{X}\to 0,$$ and the only thing I have left to do is to show that the image of the first term is disjoint from the principal Cartier divisors in order to get the requested exact sequence. If $k=\overline{k}$, this is easy and $\mathcal{O}_X(X)=\mathcal{O}_{\widetilde{X}}(\widetilde{X})=k$, but I'm wondering about the general case.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$X:U^2+V^2=0\subset \Bbb{P^2_Q}$$

$i=V/U=-U/V$ isn't regular at $[0:0:1]$ so it isn't in $O_X(X)$.

The normalization is $$Y: U^2+V^2=W^2+Z^2=UW-VZ=UZ+VW=0\subset \Bbb{P}^3_\Bbb{Q}$$

Looks a bit strange but it is an homogeneous prime ideal and with $v=V/U,w=W/U,z=Z/U$ the function field is just
$$Frac(\Bbb{Q}[v,w,z]/(1+v^2,w^2+z^2,w-vz,z+vw))=Frac(\Bbb{Q}[i,w,z]/(w-iz))$$

The morphism $Y\to X$ is

$$[U:V:W:Z]\to [U:V:W]$$

$i=V/U=W/Z$ is now regular at $[0:0:1:i]$ and $[0:0:1:-i]$ so it is in $O_Y(Y)$

Comment: Please confirm that I'm not crazy.

Comment: I think I buy this intuitively - the normalization is a resolution of singularities of this curve which is an isomorphism away from the unique singular point $(x^2+y^2)$ and the resolution has no $\Bbb Q$-points, but I would like to verify this more in the language of schemes - clearly $D(U)\cap X$ and $D(V)\cap X$ are each isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Q[i][t]$, so it comes down to the third affine patch $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Q[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$, which has normalization $(\Bbb Q[x,y]/(x^2+y^2))[y/x]\cong \Bbb Q[i][t]$ (right?).

Comment: A little in the way of a follow-up - (1) do you think there's anything to the characterization of the constant functions as the intersection of all the residue fields, and (2) do you think this can be rescued, perhaps by changing the "integral" assumption to "geometrically integral"?

Comment: I did it in the projective curve setting because the normalization is $\Bbb{P}^1_{\Bbb{Q}[i]}$ and the morphism is $[a:b]\to [a:ia:b]$ and said like this it looks a bit worrying (ie. not defined over $\Bbb{Q}$) to avoid discussing why it is I found an embedding $\Bbb{P}^1_{\Bbb{Q}[i]}\to \Bbb{P^3_Q}$. The $Spec(B_j)\to Spec(A_j)$ of the affine cover show that there is no problem but it is a bit more abstract than $[U:V:W:Z]\to [U:V:W]$

Comment: Look, I think you found the right thing, and scheme-theoretically that makes sense to me. The reason I'm asking to verify it using the schemey approach is because I still need the practice translating the "classical" method you're using here to schemes - that transition was pretty recent for me and I think I still need to be careful about it.